# Failed to collect cluster Default info java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error while creating AdminClient for Cluster Default

Tags: apache-kafka

**I would like to use network_mode: bridge for kafka for being able to reach kafka through localhost:9092 from another service**

I'm trying to use the provectus/kafka-ui but when I open the consumers menu I get the following error

[image]

**my docker-compose.yml file :**

```html
  kafka-ui:
    container_name: kafka-ui
    image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    environment:
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS: kafka:9092
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_JMXPORT: 9997

  kafka:
    image: johnnypark/kafka-zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
      - "9092:9092"
    network_mode: bridge
    environment:
      ADVERTISED_HOST: 127.0.0.1
      NUM_PARTITIONS: 1
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

**log error:**

2022-01-13 09:16:50,014 ERROR [parallel-5] c.p.k.u.s.MetricsService: Failed to collect cluster Default info

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error while creating AdminClient for Cluster Default

[image]

[provectus/kafka-ui](https://github.com/provectus/kafka-ui)

Comment: in my case the problem was due to network_mode: bridge. [The default bridge network is deprecated and will most likely not provide the requirements that Kafka needs (containers only talk to each other via IP)](https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker/issues/512#issuecomment-505759019) For this reason, I installed the structure as in the example below. Everything works now. https://github.com/provectus/kafka-ui/blob/master/docker/kafka-ui.yaml

Comment: I don't think the bridge network is your problem. That's the default behavior of Docker Compose, thus why it's deprecated. You do need to change `ADVERTISED_HOST`: to `kafka` for containers in the same network to work. Also, the image you're using for Kafka hasn't been updated in over a year, so I suggest you use a different one (with a separate Zookeeper container)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using the johnnypark/kafka-zookeeper library for both kafka and zookeeper. I was able to solve this problem by using two separate libraries as in the example below

```html
  zookeeper1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.2.4
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  kafka1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.3.1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper1
    ports:
      - 9093:9093
      - 9998:9998
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper1:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka1:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9093
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      JMX_PORT: 9998
      KAFKA_JMX_OPTS: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=kafka1 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9998
```

Answer (score 0):

> being able to reach kafka through localhost:9092 from another service

You can't use localhost to reach Kafka since that would be the Kafka UI container itself.

Changing  `ADVERTISED_HOST` to `kafka` and using `kafka:9092` from other containers is correct for a bridge network. However, this have the side effect of preventing any access to Kafka outside the Docker network, such as clients directly on the host machine.

Answer (score 0):

Internal and External clients can be configured separately. [bitnami/bitnami-docker-kafka](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-kafka#accessing-apache-kafka-with-internal-and-external-clients)

Here's an example using Bitnami's Kafka Image - this allows host clients to connect on port 9093 while allowing kafka-ui to connect with the default port.

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
    ports:
      - '2181:2181'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  kafka:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
      - '9093:9093'
    environment:
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CLIENT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=CLIENT://:9092,EXTERNAL://:9093
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=CLIENT://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9093
      - KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=CLIENT
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

  kafka-ui:
    image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui
    container_name: kafka-ui
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME=local
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS=kafka:9092
      - SERVER_PORT=8081
```